# React-Native based APK crashes on my phone

Tags: android-studio, react-native

So I took a basic react-native course on Udemy (No response from instructor). The first assignment is to make a "To-Do" list, which I made. Followed all the instructions on this page:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html
Got a successful build, and my app launches after installation but when I press the input field, it just crashes. Any idea what could be wrong?
This is my code, even though I'm quite sure the problem is somewhere else:

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    TextInput,
    View,
    TouchableOpacity,
    ScrollView,
    AsyncStorage
} from 'react-native';

const Main = React.createClass({
  getInitialState () {
return ({
tasks: [],
completedTasks:[],
task:''
})
  },

componentWillMount() {
AsyncStorage.getItem('tasks')
.then((response) => {
  this.setState ({tasks: JSON.parse(response)})
});
AsyncStorage.getItem('completedTasks')
.then((response) => {
  this.setState({completedTasks: JSON.parse(response)})
});
  },

componentDidUpdate() {
  this.setStorage();
},  

setStorage() {
    AsyncStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(this.state.tasks));
    AsyncStorage.setItem('completedTasks', JSON.stringify(this.state.completedTasks));

  },

  renderList(tasks){
return(
  tasks.map((task, index) =>{
    return(
    <View key={task} style={styles.task}>
      <Text>
      {task}
        </Text>
        <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={()=>this.completeTask(index)}
        >
        <Text>
          &#10003;
          </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
  })
)
  },
  renderCompleted(tasks) {
return (
  tasks.map((task, index) => {
    return(
      <View key={task} style={styles.task}>
        <Text style={styles.completed}>
          {task} 
          </Text>
          <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={()=>this.deleteTask(index)}
          >
            <Text>
              &#10005;
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
    )
  })
)
  },

deleteTask(index){
  let completedTasks = this.state.completedTasks;
  completedTasks = completedTasks.slice(0, index).concat(completedTasks.slice(index+1));
  this.setState({completedTasks});
},

completeTask(index) {
let tasks = this.state.tasks;
tasks = tasks.slice(0, index).concat(tasks.slice(index+1));

let completedTasks = this.state.completedTasks;
completedTasks = completedTasks.concat([this.state.tasks[index]]);

this.setState({
  tasks,
  completedTasks
});


  },
  addTask() {
   let tasks = this.state.tasks.concat([this.state.task]);
   this.setState({tasks})

  },
  render() {
    return (
   <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.header}>
        Muli's To-Do
             </Text>
            <TextInput underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'}
            style={styles.input}
            onChangeText={(text) => {
              this.setState({task: text});
            } }
            onEndEditing={()=> this.addTask()}
            />
            <ScrollView>
{this.renderList(this.state.tasks)}
            {this.renderCompleted(this.state.completedTasks)}
              </ScrollView>

            </View>
    )
  }
})

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
  flex:1,
  backgroundColor: '#3b5998'

},
header: {
color:'white',
margin: 0,
marginTop:10,
textAlign: 'center',
fontSize: 18

},
task: {
  elevation:5,
  backgroundColor:'white',
  flexDirection: 'row',
  height: 60,
  borderWidth:1,
  borderColor: 'black',
  justifyContent:'space-between',
  alignItems:'center',
  padding: 20,
  margin: 2,
  borderRadius: 5,
},
input: {
  elevation:10,
  backgroundColor:'white',
  height: 60,
  borderWidth:1,
  borderBottomWidth: 1,
  borderRadius: 5,
  borderColor:'black',
  textAlign: 'center',
  margin:10,
  marginBottom:30,
  fontSize:15,
  color: '#3b5998',
},
completed: {
  color: '#555',
  textDecorationLine: 'line-through'
}
})

module.exports = Main;
```

Please let me know about other relevant info I can provide.

Thanks!!

Comment: it was a release mode ?

Comment: @Codesingh I'm sorry, but what do you mean?

Comment: did you generate a signed apk?

Comment: Yes, I did. According to the steps on this page: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html and got a build successful message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that during `componentWillMount`, you are setting the state with undefined for both `tasks` and `completedTasks`. In fresh setup, your storage will be empty, and responses for both tasks and completedTasks will be undefined.

You can adjust the componentWillMount with a quick check if response exists, like so:

```
componentWillMount() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('tasks')
      .then((response) => {
        if (response) {
          this.setState({tasks: JSON.parse(response)})
        }
      });
    AsyncStorage.getItem('completedTasks')
      .then((response) => {
        if (response) {
          this.setState({completedTasks: JSON.parse(response)})
        }
      });
  },
```

[image: running app]

Comment: Thanks, I see what you mean! but could this be the reason for the app crashing on my device?

Comment: Yes, reason being, once you start typing, the state is updated and the component will try to re-render. While re-rendering, the method `renderList(tasks)` is invoked which in turns run the following code `tasks.map((task, index) => {`. This will throw an error since you're trying to invoke map function on a null object.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. So I'll edit it with your fix and post back. Thanks!

Comment: Sure thing, hope it helps.

Comment: It Does, Thanks so much! By the way, any idea how I can reset (empty) the input field each time I set a "To-Do"?

Comment: hurm, hopefully it's readable since I can't put a full on code in comment. Basically, set the value in `TextInput` to `this.state.task` like so `<TextInput value={this.state.task}` ... />` and set the task to empty string once finish adding. In your `addTask()`, set `state.task` to empty like so `this.setState({tasks, task: ""})` .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146636/discussion-between-siwananda-and-muli-cohen).